# Matlab Deep Learning LayerGraph Weights

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, onnx

I am using [Deep Learning Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/deep-learning.html) and have imported an [ONNX model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/importonnxnetwork.html). Now I have a Matlab variable `net` which is `1x1 Layer Graph`. Here is the information:

```
net = 

  LayerGraph with properties:

         Layers: [33×1 nnet.cnn.layer.Layer]
    Connections: [35×2 table]
     InputNames: {'Input_0'}
    OutputNames: {'RegressionLayer_Gemm_28_Flatten14RegressionLayer_Gemm_28'}
```

My question is how can I access the weights of this network and store them in a matrix? The data structure I am thinks is a `1xn` cell where `n` is the number of layers, and each cell is `a x b` size matrix where `a` and `b` are the number of neurons of each layer.